# Why is it problematic for a direction to be a linear combination of another in Powell's Method?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods

This is the algorithm for Powell's Method, as presented in a book, Numerical Methods in Engineering with Python.

The section in the book goes on to explain that, when not dealing with quadratics, the direction vectors $v_{i}$ tend to become linear combinations of one another. That is, $v_{i} = \lambda v_{m} + \omega v_{h}$. Why would this ruin the search process towards a minimum or maximum?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n$ vectors which you think span the $n$ dimensional space. If one of them is a linear combination of the rest, they only span an $n-1$ dimensional subspace and you are only minimizing over that. The true minimum may not be in that subspace, but you can't get to it.

Comment: What exactly is a **sunspace**? It would be nice to have a 10D sunspace in the winter.

Answer (score 1):

Because it reduces the dimension of the search space. Thus not every point can be reached, or, if the linear dependence is not exactly exact, it will take very many iterations to wind down to the minimum.